# MSEdge super slow when creating >1000 elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, performance, microsoft-edge

Every other browser gets through this JS almost instantly, see below benchmarks

It is slowing down only on this code in a function (rest runs instant), which is so simple its making me confused as to what I can do to fix it.

I cannot reproduce this in JSFiddle, here is the equivalent code https://jsfiddle.net/5ax7mshz/ . I can see with performance.now() that this is the only code slowing it down in our app, and its a purely JS+JQ app, there are no other variables here...somehow it takes 600x as long in our app as it does in the fiddle. Very much at my wits' end here.

Thanks All!

```
var options = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.Vendor.length; i++) {
    options += "<option value='" + data.Vendor[i].VendorID + "'>" + data.Vendor[i].Name + "</option>";
}
$el.append(options);
```

Actual benchmarking values

Average Edge benchmark (trying some of the solutions here so far unfortunately still resulted in similar values)

- 28155 ms total

  - 6968 ms list1 (2232 items)
  - 21179 ms list2 (4016 items)
  - 7.6 ms list3 (10 items)

Here's Chrome if you want some laughs

- 55.07 ms total

  - 21.09 ms list1 (2232 items)
  - 32.18 ms list2 (4016 items)
  - 1.79 ms list3 (10 items)

Aaaand Firefox takes 46ms total

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220889/discussion-on-question-by-spillai-msedge-super-slow-when-creating-1000-elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up doing this to at least make it 5-7 seconds total (5000-7000ms) instead of 28, which is 'ok' as this only affects a couple clients, rest use Chrome (50ms) and FF (40ms) and IE11+ (300ms)

```js
document.getElementById("vendor").innerHTML = "";
var i = 0;
var loop_num = 0;
var vendorCount = data.Vendor.length;
var vendorPiece;
var k = 0;
var options = [];
if (isEdge) {
  //add optgroups to select
  var num_selects = Math.ceil(vendorCount / 1000); //say, 3 for 2323
  for (var jj = 1; jj <= num_selects; jj++) {
    var optgroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
    optgroup.label = "";
    optgroup.id = "vendor" + jj;
    document.getElementById("vendor").appendChild(optgroup);
    if (jj == 1) {
      var blankopt = document.createElement("option");
      blankopt.value = "";
      blankopt.text = "";
      document.getElementById("vendor" + jj).appendChild(blankopt);
    }
  }
} else {
  var blankopt = document.createElement("option");
  blankopt.value = "";
  blankopt.text = "";
  document.getElementById("vendor").appendChild(blankopt);
}
while (i < vendorCount) {
  var pieceEndIndex =
    Math.min(1000, vendorCount - i) == 1000 ? i + 1000 : vendorCount;
  k = 0;
  options = [];
  vendorPiece = data.Vendor.slice(i, pieceEndIndex);
  for (var j = 0; j < vendorPiece.length; j++) {
    var vendor = vendorPiece[j];
    options[k++] = "<option value='";
    options[k++] = vendor.VendorID;
    options[k++] = "'>";
    options[k++] = vendor.Name;
    options[k++] = "</option>";
  }
  var vendor_id = !isEdge ? "vendor" : "vendor" + (loop_num + 1);
  document.getElementById(vendor_id).innerHTML += options.join("");
  i += vendorPiece.length;
  loop_num++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `append` you're using from jQuery?

I don't have Edge on this machine, but I do have IE, so I'll use that as a reasonable equivalent.  I tried several 4000 select-option builds:

1. String concat followed by single jQuery `append`
2. jQuery `append` per entry
3. `appendChild` per element (no jQuery)
4. add `new Option(...` to `select.options` (no jQuery)

For timing I'm using

```js
console.time('build');
build();
console.timeEnd('build');
```

And the results, two runs - fastest time (ms):

```
IE11 805 2120 605 6033
FF80  48  190  26   21
CR84  95  342  52  214
```

With 4000 elements, this is comparison to your list2, while the first timing number should match your results (although note I made up the value/text per entry, since I don't have access to your list).  Note Chrome is significantly slower than yours (95 vs 32 - 3x), and IE is significantly faster (805 vs 2117 - 26x).  For my Chrome process I have many open tabs, but there's also an update waiting, for my IE process I have nothing else open, but it's also not exactly the same as Edge (assuming you're not using Webkit Edge - if you are, then it's a very different engine)

The jQuery based builds are both poor performers.  This isn't really a fair fight, since this method has to parse a string and interpret it as HTML.  Build 4 also did poorly on everything but FireFox.  So, it looks like vanilla javascript with `appendChild` is the best approach.

To map this back to your data (which *may* have further object access delays):

```js
function build(data, select) {
  var n=data.Vendor.length;
  for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    var item=data.Vendor[i];
    var opt=document.createElement("option");
    opt.value=item.VendorID;
    opt.innerText=item.Name;
    select.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
// Call egs:
// build(data, document.getElementById("itemList"));
// build(data, document.forms[0].itemSelect);
```

Comment: please read at least the first 2 comments, i did try JS only and it still happens.

Comment: the only promising thing so far is manually splitting the array and doing array concatenation (array concat by itself wasn't enough) and even then, for objects 0-1000 it takes 1.5 seconds in Edge (10ms in FF/Chrome) and 1000-2000 it takes 11 seconds (10ms in FF/Chrome)

I then tried splicing the array into pieces of 1000 length and the 2nd piece takes 11 seconds STILL. so weird

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  As it is you're asking for help with a problem no one else can see or validate.  The comments do not show your progress

Comment: ok, well your way takes longer than the original, up to 8 seconds from 6.6

Comment: I understand, I am doing it. it takes time to make...

Comment: it does not occur when i make a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ax7mshz/ . Edge does it fast. I'm really at my wits End here. I can see with performance.now() that this is the only code slowing it down in our app, and its a purely JS+JQ app, there are no other variables here...somehow it takes 600x as long in our app as it does in the fiddle. @Rudu